# Assembly x86 - Input Issues

Tags: assembly, x86

So what im trying is to get 2 int from the user, problem is when i look at whats inside the numbers (input = 2 and 1), i've not the number, but 0xa02 and 0xa01. What am i doing wrong?

```
segment .bss

n1 resb 2
n2 resb 2
```

And the input code is

```
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, n1
mov edx, 2
int 80h
```

So when the user inputs 1, if i take a loot i get

```
print n1
$1 = 2609
```

PS: I know i must sub 48 in order to get the real number

Comment: This interrupt call uses the *address* of tour input buffer, and does not return "the number". See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm

Comment: The `0xa` is the line feed after your digit.

Comment: So, if i want to remove the LF, should i just sub that 0xa, or there is any other way to avoid getting it from the input?